# Output a list from a sentence and count characters for each word

Tags: python, string, list, count, string-length

I need to output a list with a character count in a 2 element list which gives the character count for each word:

```
[['How', 3], ['are', 3], ['you', 3], ['today', 5]]
```

I am using a function

def char(s):

```
    l = []  # list for holding your result

    # convert string s into a list of 2-element-lists
    s = text.split()
    s = [[word ,len(word)] for word in s.split()]
    print("Output:\n", s)
    print()
    return l


text = "How are you today"
l = char(text)
print()
```

but I am getting this output where it does total character count for each word instead of a specific count for each word:

```
[['How', 17], ['are', 17], ['you', 17], ['today', 17]]
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use len(w) instead of len(text)

Comment: Because len(text) is the length of the full string

Comment: @Supernova, consider using the parameter `s` that you are passing to your function instead of using `text` which is a global variable.

Comment: I tried that it gives output of 4 for each word because it counts the number of words in the string

Comment: s = text.split()
    s = ([ [word,len(s)] for word in s ])
    print("Output:\n", s)
    print()
    return l

Comment: Output:[['How', 4], ['are', 4], ['you', 4], ['today', 4]]

Comment: I was able to create two lists with the count:  s = text.split()
    x = [len(i) for i in s]
    s = [s, x]
    print("Output:\n", s)
    print()
    return l

Comment: Output  [['How', 'are', 'you', 'today'], [3, 3, 3, 5]]

Comment: I just need to merge them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are counting the number of characters in text, but you have to count the characters in every word. In the end, you could even simplify your code as:

```
def char(s):
    return [[word ,len(word)] for word in s.split()]
```

Then you can call it by:

```
text = "How are you today"
l = char(text)
print(l)
```

Ouput:

```
[['How', 3], ['are', 3], ['you', 3], ['today', 5]]
```

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf its saying has not attribute for split

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf  I have updated my code above but still generating an attribute error on split

Comment: @Supernova, I just have checked the code, and it is working like a charm. Are you passing a string to the function? Like this:
`text = "How are you today";
l = char(text)`

Comment: @Supernova, I just have updated my answer, and this is definitely working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137089/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-supernova).

Answer (score 2):

You have scoping issues.  You are calling `len()` on the outer variable `text` rather than each loop iteration, variable named `w`, thus you get the total character count for each word.

You have another issue that you calling `split()` inside your `char` function on the outer variable `text` rather than the object passed into the function, which you've called `s`.